# Users won't show up on Authentication tab in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Why is it that when I type in an email and password nothing shows up in Firebase? I've done it before with no issues.

No user entry is made when i check my Authentication tab in firebase.

```
//Sign up user
        let email = emailTextField.text
        let password = passwordTextField.text

        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail:email! , password: password!, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.login()
            } else {
                print("User created!")
                self.login()
            }
        })

    }

    @IBAction func signInButton(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    //Functions
    func login(){
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Password or email has not been entered correctly")
            } else {
                print("Successful Login")
            }

        })
    }



}
```

Comment: Try to change line to this FIRAuth.auth()!.createUser(withEmail: "check123@gmail.com", password: "123456" ......

Comment: It will localize your problem, I think

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will fix your problem, but try declaring with a guard statement, and remove your bangs (!) in the signup/login. It should at least be a lot less error prone.

```
Guard let email = emailTextField.text else { return }
Guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
```

Now remove bangs so it looks like this

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email , password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
```

And do the same for your login function, unwrap your textField texts with a guard statement.

Cheers.

Comment: Didn't work. For some reason user emails won't show up. but my code seems to work. It prints out "User created". So it should work but the emails won't show up.

Comment: When user presses the "Create Account" button on my app. The users email does not show up on firebase under the authentication tab. I made the app so that users have to enter their email and password.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong GoogleService-info.plist file. I kept using the same one because i didn't think i had to keep re-downloading them for each app.